# ¿Como buscar valores en un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda, alguien sabe como realizar una búsqueda en un objeto JSON con la función filter de javascript pero que las condiciones no sean establecidas y se tomen en base a un arreglo para su manipulacion, por ejemplo:

```
// Escuelas
var escuelas = [
  {id_escolares_pk: 1,escuela: "Gregorio",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1},
  {id_escolares_pk: 2,escuela: "Ignacio",tipo: "Privada",id_nivel_fk: 1},
  {id_escolares_pk: 3,escuela: "UTZ",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1}
];
`
`
// Arreglo con las condiciones a ejecutar
var comparaciones = ["id_nivel_fk == 1", "tipo == 'Privada'"];
`
`
// Ejecución de filter 
var encontrados = escuelas.filter(function(elemento) {
 return elemento.id_nivel_fk == 1 && elemento.tipo == "Privada" // ◄ Aquí se desea que aplique el arreglo comparaciones 
});
```

Comment: No seria mas facil si el arreglo comparaciones lo vuelves un objeto, por ejm: `var comparaciones = { id_nivel_fk: 1, tipo: "Privada" };`

Comment: Pero necesito acceder al elemento, seguido de su clave, por ejemplo:
`elemento.id_nivel_fk`
Ademas estos valores pueden cambiar, por ejemplo no siempre va a hacer el mismo objeto escuelas, lo que trato de hacer es una función que tome el rol de un filtro con N cantidad de condiciones,

Comment: ¿El operador de comparación siempre será el mismo `==`? ¿Siempre se encadenarán mediante `&&`?

Comment: Para la práctica que deseo realizar si, pero si quiero mejorarla pueden variar los operadores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una pequeña funcion filter, la cual la puedes adaptar a lo que nesecitas, prueba con esto:

```js
function filter(list, compare){
var newList = [];
var countProp = compare.length;
var countMatch = 0;
var valComp;
var valList;

for(var iList in list) {
 valList = list[iList];
 countMatch = 0;
 for(var iComp in compare){
  valComp = compare[iComp];
  if(valList.hasOwnProperty(valComp.name)) {
   if(valComp.operator === "===" && valList[valComp.name] === valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === "!==" && valList[valComp.name] !== valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === "==" && valList[valComp.name] == valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === "!=" && valList[valComp.name] != valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === "<" && valList[valComp.name] < valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === "<=" && valList[valComp.name] <= valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === ">" && valList[valComp.name] > valComp.value) countMatch++;
   else if(valComp.operator === ">=" && valList[valComp.name] >= valComp.value) countMatch++;
  }
 }
 
 if(countMatch == countProp){
  newList.push(valList);
 }
}

return newList;
}

var escuelas = [
  {id_escolares_pk: 1,escuela: "Gregorio",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1},
  {id_escolares_pk: 2,escuela: "Ignacio",tipo: "Privada",id_nivel_fk: 1},
  {id_escolares_pk: 3,escuela: "UTZ",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1}
];

var comparaciones = [
{ name: "id_nivel_fk", value: 1, operator: "==" },
{ name: "tipo", value: "Pública", operator: "==" }
];

var encontrados1 = filter(escuelas, comparaciones);

var encontrados2 = filter(escuelas, [
{ name: "id_nivel_fk", value: 1, operator: "==" },
{ name: "tipo", value: "Privada", operator: "==" }
]);

var encontrados3 = filter([
  {modelo: "MCF", cantidad: 20},
  {modelo: "JKM", cantidad: 50},
  {modelo: "ERT", cantidad: 70},
],
[
{ name: "cantidad", value: 50, operator: ">=" }
]);

console.log("encontrados1: ", encontrados1);
console.log("encontrados2: ", encontrados2);
console.log("encontrados3: ", encontrados3);
```

A la funcion se le pasa dos argumentos los cuales son un array o lista, la primera contiene los elementos a filtrar y la segunda los valores con los que se filtrara o reglas.

Se recorre cada uno de los elementos a filtrar y se comparan con cada una de las reglas de comparacion, siempre y cuando sus nombres concuerden y dependiendo del comparador que se pase a cada regla.

Por cada concordancia se aumenta la variable `countMatch` la cual despues se compara con la cantidad de reglas pasadas, si son iguales se guarda el elemento actual evaluado.

Al final del codigo e puesto `encontrados2` y `encontrados3` para referenciar que no solo es estatico para la lista escuela, si no que puedes pasar otros tipos.

Espero que te sirva de guia para lo que nesecitas.

Comment: Aunque seria genial poder hacer la funcion filter utlizando plantillas de cadena de texto y expresiones regulares.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciona perfectamente. :D

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver específicamente el problema mostrado, esta es la solución que encontré:

```js
const escuelas = [
    {id_escolares_pk: 1,escuela: "Gregorio",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1},
    {id_escolares_pk: 2,escuela: "Ignacio",tipo: "Privada",id_nivel_fk: 1},
    {id_escolares_pk: 3,escuela: "UTZ",tipo: "Pública",id_nivel_fk: 1}
];

// Arreglo con las condiciones a ejecutar
const listaCondiciones = [
    { columna: "id_nivel_fk", valor: 1, operador: "===" },
    { columna: "tipo", valor: "Pública", operador: "!==" }
];

// Ejecución de filter 
const encontrados = escuelas.filter(elemento => cumpleLasCondiciones(elemento, listaCondiciones));

// Verifica todas las condiciones para el elemento dado
function cumpleLasCondiciones(elemento, condiciones) {
    return !condiciones
        .map(condicion => evaluarCondicion(elemento, condicion))
        .includes(false);
}

function evaluarCondicion(elemento, condicion) {
  if(condicion.operador === "===") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] === condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === "!==") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] !== condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === "==") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] == condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === "!=") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] != condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === "<")
      return elemento[condicion.columna] < condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === "<=") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] <= condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === ">") 
      return elemento[condicion.columna] > condicion.valor;
  if(condicion.operador === ">=")
      return elemento[condicion.columna] >= condicion.valor;
} 

console.log(encontrados);
```

En `cumpleLasCondiciones` es donde sucede la magia.

`map(condicion => elemento[condicion.columna] === condicion.valor)` ejecuta cada comprobación y devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo si la cumple o no.

El arreglo resultante consta del resultado de estas evaluaciones, así que buscamos si alguna no se cumplió con `includes(false)`.

Finalmente, si se encontró alguna que no se cumplió (`includes`devuelve `true`), negamos el valor con `!condiciones`, lo que al final es utilizado por el `escuelas.filter` para saber si el elemento pasa o no.

Para añadir más operadores, puedes utilicé el método de Orlando, agregando una propiedad más al objeto de comparaciones y creando una función para aplicar en `map`.

Comment: super, solo debe de agregar en la lista de condiciones los valores de los operadores condicionales y los operadores logico y actualizar el callback del map, me gusta tu solucion.